# Grails controller unit tests pass on the command line and not in Intellij

Tags: grails, groovy, junit, intellij-idea, spock

I am using Grails 2.3.8 and recently I started fixing some outdated tests that stopped working in the past couple of Grails 2.3.x versions.

During a  Spock controller test, and when responding with a domain instance from a Controller, assertions against the Model fail/pass depending on the test execution environment. Specifically, when executing tests using the Grails console vs IntelliJ (Junit), the domain instance on the model has a different property name.

I have been hedging against it by making this type of assertion in my *then* or *expect* blocks in my Spock specifications:

```groovy
void "show action correctly handles a valid instance"() {

    given: "a valid domain instance"

        def myDomainObject = MyDomainClass.build()

    when: "calling the show action with a valid domain instance"

        controller.show(myDomainObject)

    then: "respond to the show view with the domain instance set on the model"

        view == ‘show’
        // the property name ends with ‘Instance’ in one env and not in the other                        
        model.myDomainObjectInstance ?: model.myDomainObject == myDomainObject
}
```

Comment: Could the person who down voted please explain why? Not trying to be argumentative, but I would like to know if there is something wrong or missing from my post that might help others to understand and respond.

Comment: I would double check that you're using the same grails version in both environments. It's easy to end up with a mismatch.

Comment: I wish it was something trivial like that, but I have a feeling it has something to do with the way the Grails environment is configured in Intellij. Everything runs fine in our production environment. Once I get some time in the next Sprint I am going to try get to root of the problem.

Comment: Any news on this? I've had the exact same problem.  I also don't want to hack my test code to make this work.  I've been running tests via the command line interface in Intellij for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that could be a problem, but I think you should be saving the response from the controller in a variable and also accessing to the view using the renderArgs variable:

void "show action correctly handles a valid instance"() {

```
given: "a valid domain instance"

    def myDomainObject = MyDomainClass.build()

when: "calling the show action with a valid domain instance"

    def model = controller.show(myDomainObject)

then: "respond to the show view with the domain instance set on the model"

    renderArgs.view == ‘show’
    // the property name ends with ‘Instance’ in one env and not in the other                        
    model.myDomainObjectInstance ?: model.myDomainObject == myDomainObject
```

}

Not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: The model is not null and contains the instance, and the assertion `view == 'show'` passes. The problem is that when running from the command line, the property name used to access the instance (on the model) is 'myDomainObject', but when running in IntelliJ it is 'myDomainObjectInstance'. As it stands, a have several dozen such tests passing, but only because I am explicitly asserting that 'myDomainObject' equals 'model.myDomainObjectInstance' *or* 'model.myDomainObject'. I am not clear why this would be happening.

Comment: I would try to check the differences between the libraries in the intellij project and the command line option

Comment: Per my comment above, I think I am leaning towards it being something like that.